# Why don't C3PO and R2D2 have each other's designs?

Tags: star-wars, droids, plot-device

If R2's job is repairing and C3PO is mainly for translating, why does R2 have the more circular body with wheels which is probably more inefficient for grabbing tools and repairing? Wouldn't it be better for R2 to have limbs and fingers with a more humanoid-based design? All C3PO has to do is translate what R2 says he could have had the wheels.

Comment: If C3PO is a protocol droid whose purpose is to interact with living beings and to aid in customs and translation, it seems to me that a humanoid appearance would be very useful as opposed to a rolling trash can.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## C3PO is a Protocol Droid

According to [Wookieepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Protocol_droid), their purpose is:

> **to assist sentients in their relations with one another**. Protocol
>   droids were programmed mostly for etiquette, and were often used as
>   translators between sentients or between sentients and computers. **They
>   were generally designed to look like the sentients they would be
>   serving; for example, 3PO-series protocol droids were humanoid.**
>
> They possessed knowledge about various cultures and customs, both to
>   advise those for whom they were working, and to ensure their own
>   behavior was diplomatic and culturally sensitive.

Hence, because C3PO was a 3PO-series protocol droid, it makes sense for C3PO to resemble a humanoid, as that's who their functioning with.  What would feel more natural to you: conversing to someone using a droid that looks like an astromech droid, bending down to talk to it, or talking with a humanoid-designed robot.

---

## R2-D2 is an Astromech Droid

Now, they're described by [Wookieepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Astromech_droid) as being:

> a type of droid that served as **an automated mechanic, performing a
>   variety of repair duties and often serving as an adjunct or substitute
>   for a nav computer on smaller starships**. Astromech droids could also
>   use the mainframes of larger ships to their advantage. Many
>   starfighters relied on astromech copilots.

Considering as part of their duties they need to go outside a starship, being portable is preferable to get the job done quickly; it would be far more difficult to *walk* outside on a spaceship than to simply *drive* around with wheels.

The other part of that quote I would draw your attention to is the fact that they are used on starfighters; these are agile, relatively small craft designed for fighting.  If you had a humanoid robot, that requires *far* more space to fit an astromech droid in rather than the small, compact design they already have.

The OP also makes the point that the non-humanoid design

> is probably more inefficient for grabbing tools and repairing

I don't *ever* recall seeing a point when R2 was required to 'pick-up' a tool.  [Wookieepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/R2-D2/Canon) lists his on-board equipment as including:

- Buzz Saw
- Electric Pike
- Fusion welder
- Scomp Link
- Power recharge coupler
- Booster rockets
- Holoprojector

So, he's pretty well-equipped without need for any other tools to pick up!

---

So, **no, R2 shouldn't have a humanoid design and 3PO's humanoid design *is* appropriate when you take into consideration their respective purposes and where they serve their respective duties!**

Comment: R2 picks up a lantern in *Empire*. That's the only case I can think of.

Comment: R2 catches (quite nicely) a com-link from Obi-Wan at the beginning of Ep. III.